# Not able to update my state variable using react useState hooks setter

Tags: reactjs, state

Below is the code for the functional component. I'm updating the state inline with onClick event handler and it displays the updated data inside the useEffect. But as soon as the control comes out of the useEffect, the state variable 'data' gets back to its previous data. I have tried updating it without useEffect first, but the problem is the same. I'm not able to access the updated state variable in other functions.

```
function Task(props) {
    var initialData = {
        id: '1',
        content: 'somecontent',
        linkedPage: 'somepage',
    };

    const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(data);
    }, [data]);

    const saveTask = () => {
        console.log(data);
        const obj = {
            name: data.content,
            id: data.id,
        };
    };
```

this is the button where I'm updating the state

```
                                       <button
                                        className="btn btn-sm btn-secondary px-4"
                                        id={props.task.id}
                                        onClick={() =>
                                            setData({
                                                ...data,
                                                id: props.task.id,
                                                content: props.task.content,
                                                linkedPage: props.task.linkedPage,
                                            })
                                        }
                                        data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#exampleModalCenterViewss"
                                    >
                                        Edit
                                    </button>
```

Please someone explain me why the state is not updating properly.

Comment: where is `saveTask` invoked ?

Comment: Where do you use `<Task /> `?

Comment: saveTask is invoked from a button that is in the modal that appears after the Edit button is clicked

Comment: @Dilshan <Task /> is used in it's parent component. But can i know why that would be needed

Comment: @AliBahaari the problem is the state variable data does not have the updated state value in saveTask() function, which runs after this button is clikced . <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-secondary"
        data-dismiss="modal"
        onClick={saveTask}
       >
        Save
       </button>

Comment: add sample in codesandbox.io for debugging is better

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use vars - **bad practice**. Learn the differences between var and let/const.
The second thing is that you don't need to write this line: setData({...data}).
The proper way to update the state is this one:

```
setData(prevData  => ({ ...prevData, 
                        id: props.task.id,
                        content: props.task.content,                         
                        linkedPage: props.task.linkedPage }))
```

setState in functional components can take a callback function instead of a piece of data, because it works asynchronously, and to get **previousData**, you need to get it from this callback function.

Comment: But even with this , the problem remains that when the save button is pressed , the data variable still have the old value itself                                                                                                                                             
 P.S : vars is bad practice, you're right. I made it vars instead of const bcoz i wanted to use it as sort of global variable inside this component.